# SQL Server view columns have wrong case

Tags: sql-server

I have a table I am trying to create a view of to work with a new reporting application that needs specific columns. I would think this should be straightforward, but the column names are in the wrong case. Specifically, one column is Customer_ID instead of changing to customer_id as specified in the SQL statement used to create the view.

The original table is: `Customer_ID | CustomerAddress | CustomerPhone`

The view needs to be: `customer_id | customer_address | customer_phone`

The view is: `Customer_ID | customer_address | customer_phone`

The command to create the view is:

```
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @sql_customers nvarchar(max) = 'CREATE VIEW customers AS SELECT
  oldcustomers.Customer_ID as customer_id,
  oldcustomers.CustomerAddress as customer_address,
  oldcustomers.CustomerPhone as customer_phone
  FROM oldcustomers'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql_customers
END
```

Comment: Can't reproduce in sql server 2016.

Comment: Works in SQL Server Express 2014

Comment: Cannot reproduce in SQL Server 2017.

Comment: What is the default collation of the database?

Comment: Why is this dynamic? Are you maybe running this in the wrong db?  Try `EXECUTE dbname..sp_executesql @sql_customers` to test?

Comment: You have `begin` and `end` -- is there an IF above this that might stop it executing?  Easy test add `SELECT DB_NAME()` right before the EXECUTE and make sure its returned in SSMS... make sure you're entering the IF.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use aliases to change the case unless you're using a case sensitive collation.

The following should do the trick w/o having to jump through hoops...

```
CREATE VIEW customers
AS
    SELECT
        oc.customer_id,
        oc.customeraddress,
        oc.customerphone
    FROM
        dbo.oldcustomers oc;
```

Comment: This won't solve it, he says the view needs `_` in the address and phone column name... so alias' are required on them.

Comment: @DaveCullum - Good catch... Whe I first looked at it, it looked like the OP was just lower casing the existing name.